# using shift key as control in emacs

Tags: emacs

I started using caps lock key as control key but turns out it is really uncomfortable for me to do so. 
I wanted to be able to use the left shift as control key and caps as left shift key. Left control being left as left control

I couldn't find any documentation which could help me do that .

Has someone tried this ?

Comment: If it's been done, it'll be on http://emacswiki.org/

Comment: Laptop? PC? Operating System?

Comment: If you are on Windows, consider using SharpKeys to remap your keyboard.  http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/

Comment: I am using PC and ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Looks like there's an answer in an ubuntu forum... http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys

Comment: Hey Eric, I don't want to remap keys in ubuntu, I want it specifically for emacs.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend this. If you are not using both <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys (which basically in any "language" whether it be a programming language or not), then you should really get used to using both.

The benefit gained from having <kbd>Control</kbd> as <kbd>Shift</kbd> does not really outweigh it.

Also, you should probably only use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as <kbd>Control</kbd> if you are using a laptop. Otherwise, you might want to learn to use <kbd>Control</kbd> with the palm of your hand.

Many articles are written on this, here I kind of present the summary. Perhaps later I'll look for the references.

Comment: Hey, I am using both shift keys. therefore I wanted caps lock to become shift key. I don't use caps lock keys too much. Which also I could change in emacs as a combination of some keys to emulate caps lock.

Comment: The idea of using both shift keys is that it minimizes stress, because one Shift will always be the "easier" one to choose.

Comment: Consider LeftShift+ z. It is a lot easier to type using the other Shift.